# Exclude certain records from table query with conditions from other several tables

Tags: sql, join

The title is not very descriptive but I need the following.
Suppose we have the following scheme and data:

```
-- main table with issues
create table i (
  id integer not null primary key
);

-- params for issues
create table p (
  id integer not null primary key,
  i_id integer not null references i (id)
);

-- params of type n
create table pn (
  id   integer not null primary key,
  p_id integer not null references p (id),
  val  integer
);

-- params of type d
create table pd (
  id   integer not null primary key,
  p_id integer not null references p (id),
  val  integer
);

-- data

-- 2 issues
insert into i values (1), (2);

-- 3 params for 2 issues
insert into p values (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2);

-- param of type n for issue 1
insert into pn values (1, 1, 1);

-- params of type d for issues 1 and 2
insert into pd values (1, 2, 1), (2, 3, 1);
```

I make the following query:

```
select
  i.id i_id,
  p.id p_id,
  pn.id pn_id, pn.val pn_val,
  pd.id pd_id, pd.val pd_val
from i
  join p on i.id = p.i_id
  left join pn on p.id = pn.p_id
  left join pd on p.id = pd.p_id
where
  pn.val = 1
  or
  pd.val = 1
;
```

The result is

```
+----+----+-----+------+-----+------+
|i_id|p_id|pn_id|pn_val|pd_id|pd_val|
+----+----+-----+------+-----+------+
|1   |2   |null |null  |1    |1     |
|2   |3   |null |null  |2    |1     |
|1   |1   |1    |1     |null |null  |
+----+----+-----+------+-----+------+
```

As you see 1st and 3rd records for issue #1 which has both `pn.val = 1` *and* `pd.val = 1`. 2nd record has only `pd.val = 1` and no `pn.val = 1`. So I need to exclude issue #2 from the results.

Not sure whether it can be done just using joins (without unions or sub selects) but I wish to.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3e71e/1/0) is the link to SQL Fiddle, thanks.

Comment: Can you add sample table data and also _specify_ the expected result - both as properly formatted text (no images.) I.e. a [mcve].

Comment: @jarlh the sample schema and data were in the question above which are the minimal reproducible example. I've also added the results table as text. Hope it helps to pick up a problem in my question easier.

Comment: I see, I thought you meant the _current_ result is, but you meant the _desired_ result is. OR?

Comment: @jarlh I meant the result for the sql query applying the schema and data above. This result is not exactly what I want and I need help to somehow modify the query to exclude 2nd row from it, so finally I would have issues with conditions from both joined tables.

Answer (score 0):

EXISTS may help here, change your where clause like this

```
WHERE
  (pn.val = 1 OR pd.val = 1)
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM pn pn_sub
    WHERE pn_sub.p_id = p.id AND pn_sub.val = 1
  )
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM pd pd_sub
    WHERE pd_sub.p_id = p.id AND pd_sub.val = 1
  );
```

I tried this in your fiddle, it returned 0 result set, was that your intended output?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, this works because you have pn and pd so the count is 2, to have1 in both columns
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3e71e/30)

**Query 1**:

```
WITH CTE aS (select
  i.id i_id,
  p.id p_id,
  pn.id pn_id, pn.val pn_val,
  pd.id pd_id, pd.val pd_val
from i
  join p on i.id = p.i_id
  left join pn on p.id = pn.p_id
  left join pd on p.id = pd.p_id
where
  (pn.val = 1
  or
  pd.val = 1))
  SELECT * FROM CTE
  WHERE
  i_id IN(SELECT i_id
          FROM CTE
  GROUP BY 1
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3e71e/30/0)**:

```
| i_id | p_id |  pn_id | pn_val |  pd_id | pd_val |
|------|------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|    1 |    2 | (null) | (null) |      1 |      1 |
|    1 |    1 |      1 |      1 | (null) | (null) |
```